# CSS responsive height of div behind the circle

Tags: css

is it possible to create this patern in css with responsive design, so that background line is always at the right position and the right height no mather how big the size of the window is.

[image]

Comment: Probably.  What have you tried?  See how to [create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements to create this, but to create perfect responsive circle you can use `vh` units on both `height` and `width` of circle. Then you can just use `position: absolute` and `transform: translate()` to position pseudo-elements.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #E54B4B;
}
.circle:before,
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.circle:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100vw;
  background: #B65657;
  height: 20vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
.circle:after {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Oh never saw this transform before. That's what I was looking for. Thank you.